# When Sudoku met Ratio

Tags: mathematics, sudoku

<sub>Continuing on from [my previous sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40709/alphabetical-sudoku)...</sub>

---

I found an old piece of paper with a sudoku solution on it and vaguely remember solving it. This is unlike a simple solution however. You get *no* starting numbers.

Here's your grid:

[image]

The fractions are ratios. For instance 1/2 could be any pair of numbers in those two squares with the ratio 1:2, or 2:1 (it can be reversed to what it says) so 1 - 2, 2 - 1, 2 - 4, 4 - 2, 3 - 6, 6 - 3, 4 - 8, 8 - 4.  Otherwise it is normal sudoku rules.

If anyone is unsure about what I mean then just ask an I'll try and explain

---

<sub>I'm not sure, but I think I found this on a website, so if I did then I don't claim this as my own...</sub>

Comment: The middle row of the top-left 9 is (3,6,8). That's as much effort as I'm willing to put in. I'm generally bad at regular Sudoku; this looks impossible. :O

Comment: @IanMacDonald it cannot be due to the `5/8` in the same row.

Comment: That's because I obviously meant (3,6,4). :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is at the bottom, but note:

> There are $3$ solutions.
>  Whoever made this puzzle must have spent quite some time making it, it's a shame it's not a proper sudoku after all that work.

Step 1

> Only possibility for these four due to the `5/8` on the same row:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 2:

> Those restrict these four:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+-------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+-------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 3:

> The `1/9` removes `9` from the `2/3` pairs in the same row, and the placed values then restrict this one:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 4:

> The `1/6` removes `6` from the `1/3` pair in the same row, and the placed values then restrict these four:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 5:

> The other `2/3` in the row with the `1/9` now must be:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 6:

> And the `1/9`, `1/8` can only be:
>
> ```
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 7:

> The `5/9` and `2/5` can only be:
>
> ```
> · 5 2 | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · 9 5 | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ```

Step 8:

> The `1/2` at the bottom can only be:
>
> ```
> · 5 2 | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · 9 5 | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · 8 4 | · · ·
> ```

Step 9:

> The `1/2` in top-middle can only be:
>
> ```
> · 5 2 | · · · | · · ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · 3 6 | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · 9 5 | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · 8 4 | · · ·
> ```

Step 10:

> The `1/2` and `2/3` at the top could be:
>
> ```
> · 5 2 | · · 3 | 6 4 ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · · | · · ·
> · · · | · 3 6 | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · 9 5 | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · 8 4 | · · ·
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> · 5 2 | · · 8 | 4 6 ·
> 3 6 4 | 1 · . | . . ·
> · · · | · 3 6 | · · ·
> ------+-------+------
> · 9 5 | · · · | · · ·
> · · · | · · · | · · ·
> 2 3 · | 6 4 9 | 1 8 ·
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 · · | · · ·
> · · 9 | 3 6 1 | · · ·
> · · · | · 8 4 | · · ·
> ```
>
> The `5/8` could be either `58` or `85` in the first case, but only `58` in the second.
>  The bottom right `2/3` is all that remains which could be `23`, `32`, `69`, or `96` (one of the last two being impossible in each of the two cases).

Step 11

> The first of the two has no solutions
>  The second has three solutions (all `23` and `32` cases for bottom-right do not work out):
>
> ```
> 1 5 2 | 9 7 8 | 4 6 3
> 3 6 4 | 1 2 5 | 8 7 9
> 9 7 8 | 4 3 6 | 5 1 2
> ------+-------+------
> 4 9 5 | 8 1 2 | 7 3 6
> 8 1 6 | 7 5 3 | 9 2 4
> 2 3 7 | 6 4 9 | 1 8 5
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 9 7 | 3 5 8
> 5 8 9 | 3 6 1 | 2 4 7
> 7 2 3 | 5 8 4 | 6 9 1
>
> 1 5 2 | 9 7 8 | 4 6 3
> 3 6 4 | 1 2 5 | 8 7 9
> 9 7 8 | 4 3 6 | 5 1 2
> ------+-------+------
> 4 9 5 | 8 1 3 | 7 2 6
> 8 1 6 | 7 5 2 | 9 3 4
> 2 3 7 | 6 4 9 | 1 8 5
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 9 7 | 3 5 8
> 5 8 9 | 3 6 1 | 2 4 7
> 7 2 3 | 5 8 4 | 6 9 1
>
> 1 5 2 | 9 7 8 | 4 6 3
> 3 6 4 | 1 2 5 | 8 7 9
> 9 7 8 | 4 3 6 | 5 1 2
> ------+-------+------
> 8 9 5 | 7 1 3 | 2 4 6
> 4 1 6 | 8 5 2 | 9 3 7
> 2 3 7 | 6 4 9 | 1 8 5
> ------+-------+------
> 6 4 1 | 2 9 7 | 3 5 8
> 5 8 9 | 3 6 1 | 7 2 4
> 7 2 3 | 5 8 4 | 6 9 1
> ```

Comment: Since there were some FGITW, I took my time to write up my steps.

Comment: Thanks for this, never knew there were multiple solutions!

Answer (score 7):

I believe there are actually a few possible solutions to this. The first one by Gareth, and here are the others:

> `1 5 2 9 7 8 4 6 3
>  3 6 4 1 2 5 8 7 9
>  9 7 8 4 3 6 5 1 2
>  4 9 5 8 1 X 7 Y 6
>  8 1 6 7 5 Y 9 X 4
>  2 3 7 6 4 9 1 8 5
>  6 4 1 2 9 7 3 5 8
>  5 8 9 3 6 1 2 4 7
>  7 2 3 5 8 4 6 9 1`
>
> The X's and Y's can resolve to two more solutions: X=2 and Y=3 or X=3 and Y=2. (For the record, Gareth and I have the same numbers in all of the "Ratio" slots; a few others are different because of a split path that I came across when coming close to solving it).

Comment: You might be right. I got near to the end, thought "hmm, it's not obvious how to narrow this down further", made an arbitrary choice and reported the solution I gave above. Then I did what I thought was a quick verification that the other way to make the choice led to a contradiction -- but I may not have done that carefully enough :-).

Comment: yes I got a similar solution where I just picked a number and continued until I had a complete solution, I think kiwi found all three possible answers.

Comment: Nice - my working through agrees, and I've double checked it all using my computer too.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the solution is

> `1 5 2 9 7 8 4 6 3
>  3 6 4 1 2 5 8 7 9
>  9 7 8 4 3 6 5 1 2
>  8 9 5 7 1 3 2 4 6
>  4 1 6 8 5 2 9 3 7
>  2 3 7 6 4 9 1 8 5
>  6 4 1 2 9 7 3 5 8
>  5 8 9 3 6 1 7 2 4
>  7 2 3 5 8 4 6 9 1`

(No cleverness to report; just a standard inference-by-inference solution process.)

Comment: Gah, just as I was typing my solution up... haha. Our solutions match, so chances are you're right :)

Comment: Aw, I was working on this. D:

Answer (score 2):

another solution -

> 152  978  463
>  364  125  879
>  978  436  512
>
>  495  812  736
>  816  753  924
>  237  649  185
>
>  641  297  358
>  589  361  247
>  723  584  691

Looks like it agrees with Kiwi's.  found by picking a value where there was a split solution, and turns out multiple choices work fine.